# Wait task and Join Task

Tags: join, workflow, wait, netflix

I'm creating a workflow using Join and Wait tasks but I don't really understand how it works. When I try, I get an Internal Server Error.

Concerning the "JOIN" task, what I thought is the join task was completed when the different tasks in the fork are completed but it is not the case. So, I don't really understand the interest of this task.

This is an example of my workflow:

```
[{
  "name": "sendMySms",
  "description": "Simple http flow",
  "version": 3,
  "tasks": [{
      "name": "fork_join",
      "taskReferenceName": "forkx",
      "type": "FORK_JOIN",
      "forkTasks": [
        [{
            "startDelay": 0,
            "name": "wait_status_affected",
            "taskReferenceName": "wait_status_affected",
            "type": "WAIT"
          },
          {
            "name": "send_my_sms",
            "taskReferenceName": "send_sms",
            "inputParameters": {
              "http_request": {
                "uri": "http://localhost:10200/Notify/NotifySms?phone_number=${workflow.input.phone_number}&message=${workflow.input.message}",
                "method": "POST",
                "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
              }
            },
            "type": "HTTP",
            "startDelay": 0
          }
        ],
        [{
          "name": "send_my_sms2",
          "taskReferenceName": "send_sms_2",
          "inputParameters": {
            "http_request": {
              "uri": "http://localhost:10200/Notify/NotifySms?phone_number=${workflow.input.phone_number}&message=${workflow.input.message2}",
              "method": "POST",
              "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
          },
          "type": "HTTP",
          "startDelay": 0
        }]
      ],
      "startDelay": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Claim Affected",
      "taskReferenceName": "ClaimAffected",
      "startDelay": 60,
      "callbackAfterSeconds": 10,
      "type": "JOIN",
      "joinOn": [
        "send_my_sms",
        "send_my_sms2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "send_my_sms3",
      "taskReferenceName": "send_sms_3",
      "inputParameters": {
        "http_request": {
          "uri": "http://localhost:10200/Notify/NotifyEmail?subject=Info&mail_to=test@mytest.com&message=fin",
          "method": "POST",
          "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      },
      "type": "HTTP",
      "startDelay": 0
    }
  ],
  "schemaVersion": 2
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A FORK_JOIN task forks a parallel set of tasks. Each set is scheduled to be executed in parallel. But tasks within a set execute serially.

In your case, you have 2 sets of parallel tasks: [wait_status_affected, send_sms] and [send_sms_2]

A WAIT task remains in IN_PROGRESS states until marked as COMPLETED or FAILED by an external trigger (e.g. Swagger).

So, send_sms won't start start until wait_status_affected is marked completed as these 2 will be scheduled serially.

The JOIN task, ClaimAffected waits for [send_my_sms, send_my_sms2]. But they are Task names, not task reference names. The corresponding task reference names are send_sms and send_sms_2.

taskReferenceName is the name which other tasks in the workflow use to refer a task.

The joinOn attribute expects a list of task reference name for which JOIN task will wait for completion. So, change your joinOn to ["send_sms","send_sms_2"]